# Java Beans Activation Framework Utilisation

Tags: java, frameworks

my company use log4j who needs Java Beans. the problem is we just use Java Beans, but the whole framework must be included into the source code. Is it possible to keep just the concerning part and delete other "useless" source code, to minimize the code size?

Comment: Technically, yes. Practically, not a good ROI. But what do you mean by "needs Java Beans"? If you look at the log4j pom, most (all?) dependencies listed are test, provided, or optional.

Comment: in fact, i'm not sure. I touch this part just ten minutes. the manager told me we used only Java Beans who is a part of pack 3 and Java 8 allowed several levels of pack but we need add the whole pack 3 just for Java Beans service. so i hope to know how to "pick out" all the dependency libraries and delete all others. or perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: I have no idea what that even means.

Comment: If you need beans just for log4j you should ask yourself why you are bothering with that mess. If you want minimize code size, use the logging API that’s built in to Java. This logging API is even within the [compact1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/compact1-package-frame.html) profile.